# showing gallery of category

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm working on a website. My client want me to show the gallery of the categories on homepage. I tried featured categories beta extension, which didn't work. Please suggest some any other free extension which I can use or any methods display it.Please, I'm a budding developer.

Answer (score 0):

You mean having a slider showing for each category in a block ?

You should consider duplicating the functions used for the main menu (see under /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php to see how it works) and combine it with your custom layout.

Or you can do it by yourself

```
Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories();
```

Will return an array of all level 1 categories in your current store.

Then you can run a foreach code to create your slideshow as you want.

Best Regards,